# Show that the CFG with productions S→ a | Sa | bSS | SSb | SbS is ambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar

How does one know which string to choose when nothing is given in the question?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You can use $abaa$. Try it yourself; if you get stuck, I’ve left two leftmost derivations in the spoiler-protected block below.

> $S\Rightarrow Sa\Rightarrow SbSa\Rightarrow abSa\Rightarrow abaa$ and $S\Rightarrow SbS\Rightarrow abS\Rightarrow abSa\Rightarrow abaa$

Comment: I would like to know how you guessed the string abaa ?

Comment: @Paritosh: I began with the idea that starting with $S\to Sa$ and following that with one of the last three productions would yield a $4$-character string ending in $a$. Alternatively, if I began with $S\to bSS$ or $S\to SbS$, I could eventually use $S\to Sa$ to get a $4$-character string ending in $a$. Then it was just a matter of picking the right productions of the form $S\to xxx$ to end up with the same string.

Answer (score 0):

I generally start by looking for a single production with repeated nonterminals that easily generate the same sequence twice.  In your case I 'hit jackpot' with the last: S -> SbS.  This generates the sequence SbSbS two ways: (SbS)bS and Sb(SbS).  I don't think the same thing happens with S->bSS or S->SSb.

Failing that, I would try to combine two or more productions to achieve the same effect.  This works with the productions S->bSS and S->SSb, which combine to produce the string bSSSb two ways: (bSS)Sb or bS(SSb).

Failing that, look for ways to produce the same terminal(s) at different heights of the parse tree.  That leads to the approach implied by @Brian M. Scott.